# On-screen buttons to emulate keyboard characters? (web)

Tags: button, emulation

I'm making a game similar to the proper franchise "Agar," and on mobile I'd like the players to be able to split and eject mass. For this, I was wondering whether I could make on-screen buttons which emulate the keys "W" for example. Thus, clicking it will eject mass.

I did some searching and I discovered something called "accesskey" in HTML, but this requires the user to also click on ALT (or whatever their browser supports) to trigger it. Is there something similar to this which does not require ALT, and just needs the key (e.g. "w") to shoot? I'd just like it to click W for you, not execute a function upong clicking W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use JQuery, in your javascript code, put something like:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 87) {
        ejectMass();
    }
});
```